# How should I represent the basis of column space of the following matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

On a homework question I am being asked to find a basis for the column space of a matrix **A**:

**A** = $$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 4 & -2 & 1 & 1 \\
2 & 5 & 4 & -2 & 2 \\
4 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
2 & -4 & 2 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 4 & 2 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I put it **A** in reduced-row echelon form and got the identity matrix $I_5$

$I_5$ = $$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

I have been following the method used in Ron Larson's *Elementary Linear Algebra 8e* which states that any nonzero column will contribute to the basis for the column space of **A**. My question regarding this problem is what would my column space look like? I looked at the solution to the question and it has the basis for the column space as follows:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 2 \\ 4 \\ 2 \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix} 4 \\ 5 \\ 3 \\ -4 \\ 1 \\ \end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix} -2 \\ 4 \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ 4 \\ \end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -2 \\ 1 \\ -1 \\ 2 \\ \end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 2 \\ 1 \\ -1 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

I understand since we got the identity matrix, this is just 1 times each respective column from the original matrix **A**, but I'm confused why the basis isn't this:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ \end{bmatrix} $$

because this is what is left over from putting **A** in reduced row echelon form. So wouldn't the nonzero columns of **A** in reduced row echelon form, i.e. $I_5$ form the basis for the column space of **A**?

Are these both bases for the column space of **A**? Is only one correct? I'm trying to decide which one to write down as my final answer and I don't know which one the grader would consider correct, incorrect or if they would even care.

Comment: Both are correct. Given the method you're using, only the first basis is "safe", in the sense that it is the basis that the method you're using spits out at the end. Of course, real vector spaces have infinitely many bases (except the trivial one), so other bases will be correct. The fact that you got a full set of $5$ vectors in $\Bbb{R}^5$ as your basis for the columnspace tells us the column space of the matrix is $\Bbb{R}^5$, so the second basis (the standard basis of $\Bbb{R}^5$) will also suffice.

Comment: @TheoBendit thank you for the clarification, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grader would consider the solution given in your book as the correct answer. For this question both bases vectors that you presented span $R^5$ which would mean they span the same space but the representation of that space is different between the $I_5$ identity matrix and the matrix presented in the problem.